# Prevent generation of empty @XmlType annotation from XSD with JAXB

Tags: null, jaxb, unmarshalling, xmlstreamreader

Let me start with what my question boils down to. I am generating a class named MyServiceResponse from an XSD schema using the maven-jaxb2-plugin. The resulting MyServiceResponse class contains `@XmlType` annotations with an empty name attribute.

```
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {

    })
```

I'd like to either generate MyServiceResponse with filled `name` attributes OR without `@XmlType` annotations altogether. Is this possible using a custom binding in a XJB file or in some other way? In any case, I want to solve this **during generation** if that is possible, because manual edits to MyserviceResponse will get overwritten on every run of the Maven plugin.

Below is a Java class that demonstrates my actual problem. The class uses an XmlStreamReader and JAXB to unmarshall XML messages starting from any element in the message. The 'xml' variable does not get fully unmarshalled. The 'car' property stays `null`. This happens because the `xmlns="http://www.example.com/type"` namespace gets copied to the Body element by the XmlStreamReader, but not to the Car child element. Somehow JAXB is unable to see that I want it to continue unmarshalling the Car element. (Big question mark here)

I already know some fixes, but they involve manual changes to the XSD or the MyServiceResponse class.

**First**, I could set `elementFormDefault="qualified"` on the XSD from which I generate the MyServiceResponse class, the ObjectFactory and a package-info.java. This works, but it also causes my request XML message to be marshalled with qualified name spaces and this is not accepted by the service that I send the message to. Also, it requires a change in the XSD which I prefer to avoid if possible.

**Secondly**, setting names on the Body and Car @XmlType annotations works: `@XmlType(name = "Body", propOrder = {})` and `@XmlType(name = "Car", propOrder = {})`. But it involves manually editing MyServiceResponse.

**Thirdly**, Removing the `@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {})` annotations works, but it also involves manual editing of MyServiceResponse.

This is a copy-pastable demo class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;

public class XmlStreamReaderUnmarshallingTest {

    private static JAXBContext jaxbContext;

    static {
        try {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
            "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" \n" +
            "\txmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" \n" +
            "\txmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">\n" +
            "\t<soapenv:Body>\n" +
            "\t\t<response xmlns=\"http://www.example.com/type\">\n" +
            "\t\t\t<type:serviceResponse xmlns:type=\"http://www.example.com/type\">\n" +
            "\t\t\t\t<Body>\n" +
            "\t\t\t\t\t<Car>\n" +
            "\t\t\t\t\t\t<Brand>Mitsubishi</Brand>\n" +
            "\t\t\t\t\t\t<Color>Red</Color>\n" +
            "\t\t\t\t\t</Car>\n" +
            "\t\t\t\t</Body>\n" +
            "\t\t\t</type:serviceResponse>\n" +
            "\t\t</response>\n" +
            "\t</soapenv:Body>\n" +
            "</soapenv:Envelope>";


    private static String xmlStripped = "<type:serviceResponse xmlns:type=\"http://www.example.com/type\">\n" +
            "\t\t\t\t<Body>\n" +
            "\t\t\t\t\t<Car>\n" +
            "\t\t\t\t\t\t<Brand>Mitsubishi</Brand>\n" +
            "\t\t\t\t\t\t<Color>Red</Color>\n" +
            "\t\t\t\t\t</Car>\n" +
            "\t\t\t\t</Body>\n" +
            "\t\t\t</type:serviceResponse>";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException {
        readXml(xml, "serviceResponse");
        readXml(xmlStripped, "serviceResponse");
    }

    private static void readXml(String inputXml, String startFromElement) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException {

        final XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        final Reader reader = new StringReader(inputXml);
        final XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(reader);
        final XMLStreamReader streamReader = skipToElement(xmlStreamReader, startFromElement);
        final MyServiceResponse serviceResponse = (MyServiceResponse) unmarshal(streamReader);

        if(serviceResponse.getBody().getCar() == null) {
            System.out.println("It didn't work :-(");
        } else {
            System.out.println("It worked");
        }
    }

    private static XMLStreamReader skipToElement(final XMLStreamReader xsr, final String startAtElement) throws XMLStreamException {
        while (startAtElement != null && xsr.hasNext()) {
            xsr.next();
            if (xsr.hasName()) {
                final String name = xsr.getName().getLocalPart();
                if (name.equals(startAtElement)) {
                    return xsr;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Could not find element %s in response", startAtElement));
    }

    private static Object unmarshal(final XMLStreamReader xsr) throws JAXBException {
        final Object entity = unmarshaller(jaxbContext).unmarshal(xsr);
        return (entity instanceof JAXBElement ? ((JAXBElement) entity).getValue() : entity);
    }

    // Create unmarshaller every time
    private static Unmarshaller unmarshaller(JAXBContext context) throws JAXBException {

        return context.createUnmarshaller();

    }
}


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "MyServiceResponse", propOrder = {

})
class MyServiceResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "Body")
    protected MyServiceResponse.Body body;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the body property.
     *
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link MyServiceResponse.Body }
     *
     */
    public MyServiceResponse.Body getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the body property.
     *
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link MyServiceResponse.Body }
     *
     */
    public void setBody(MyServiceResponse.Body value) {
        this.body = value;
    }


    /**
     * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
     *
     * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
     *
     * <pre>
     * &lt;complexType&gt;
     *   &lt;complexContent&gt;
     *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType"&gt;
     *       &lt;all&gt;
     *         &lt;element name="Car" minOccurs="0"&gt;
     *           &lt;complexType&gt;
     *             &lt;complexContent&gt;
     *               &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType"&gt;
     *                 &lt;all&gt;
     *                   &lt;element name="Brand" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
     *                   &lt;element name="Color" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
     *                 &lt;/all&gt;
     *               &lt;/restriction&gt;
     *             &lt;/complexContent&gt;
     *           &lt;/complexType&gt;
     *         &lt;/element&gt;
     *       &lt;/all&gt;
     *     &lt;/restriction&gt;
     *   &lt;/complexContent&gt;
     * &lt;/complexType&gt;
     * </pre>
     *
     *
     */
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {

    })
    public static class Body {

        @XmlElement(name = "Car")
        protected MyServiceResponse.Body.Car car;

        /**
         * Gets the value of the car property.
         *
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link MyServiceResponse.Body.Car }
         *
         */
        public MyServiceResponse.Body.Car getCar() {
            return car;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the value of the car property.
         *
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link MyServiceResponse.Body.Car }
         *
         */
        public void setCar(MyServiceResponse.Body.Car value) {
            this.car = value;
        }


        /**
         * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
         *
         * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
         *
         * <pre>
         * &lt;complexType&gt;
         *   &lt;complexContent&gt;
         *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType"&gt;
         *       &lt;all&gt;
         *         &lt;element name="Brand" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
         *         &lt;element name="Color" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
         *       &lt;/all&gt;
         *     &lt;/restriction&gt;
         *   &lt;/complexContent&gt;
         * &lt;/complexType&gt;
         * </pre>
         *
         *
         */
        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {

        })
        public static class Car {

            @XmlElement(name = "Brand")
            protected String brand;
            @XmlElement(name = "Color")
            protected String color;

            /**
             * Gets the value of the brand property.
             *
             * @return
             *     possible object is
             *     {@link String }
             *
             */
            public String getBrand() {
                return brand;
            }

            /**
             * Sets the value of the brand property.
             *
             * @param value
             *     allowed object is
             *     {@link String }
             *
             */
            public void setBrand(String value) {
                this.brand = value;
            }

            /**
             * Gets the value of the color property.
             *
             * @return
             *     possible object is
             *     {@link String }
             *
             */
            public String getColor() {
                return color;
            }

            /**
             * Sets the value of the color property.
             *
             * @param value
             *     allowed object is
             *     {@link String }
             *
             */
            public void setColor(String value) {
                this.color = value;
            }

        }

    }

}


@XmlRegistry
class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName _ServiceResponse_QNAME = new QName("http://www.example.com/type", "serviceResponse");

    /**
     * Create a new ObjectFactory that can be used to create new instances of schema derived classes for package: com.example.type
     *
     */
    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link MyServiceResponse }
     *
     */
    public MyServiceResponse createMyServiceResponse() {
        return new MyServiceResponse();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link MyServiceResponse.Body }
     *
     */
    public MyServiceResponse.Body createMyServiceResponseBody() {
        return new MyServiceResponse.Body();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link MyServiceResponse.Body.Car }
     *
     */
    public MyServiceResponse.Body.Car createMyServiceResponseBodyCar() {
        return new MyServiceResponse.Body.Car();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link MyServiceResponse }{@code >}}
     *
     */
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.example.com/type", name = "serviceResponse")
    public JAXBElement<MyServiceResponse> createServiceResponse(MyServiceResponse value) {
        return new JAXBElement<MyServiceResponse>(_ServiceResponse_QNAME, MyServiceResponse.class, null, value);
    }

}
```

My XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.example.com/type"
           targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/type" elementFormDefault="qualified" >
    <xs:element name="serviceResponse" type="MyServiceResponse"/>
    <xs:complexType name="MyServiceResponse">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="Body" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:all>
                        <xs:element name="Car" minOccurs="0">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:all>
                                    <xs:element name="Brand" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                    <xs:element name="Color" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                </xs:all>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:all>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**Added:**

This is the XML that is in the XmlStreamReader when it starts unmarshalling. JAXB unmarshalls the ServiceResponse element, the Body, but not Car.

```
<type:serviceResponse xmlns:type="http://www.example.com/type"> 
    <Body xmlns="http://www.example.com/type"> 
        <Car> 
            <Brand>Mitsubishi</Brand> 
            <Color>Red</Color> 
        </Car> 
    </Body> 
</type:serviceResponse>
```

Answer (score 2):

`@XmlType` name's attribute is empty because Car and Body are anonymous types. (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlType.html)

Create `complexTypes` in the global namespace and use them as the `type` of the `element`. (Small snippet)

```
<xs:element name="Body" type="Body" minOccurs="0" />
<xs:complexType name="Body">
```

Or create a JAXB binding like this: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-avoid-anonymous-types/#N100BB

Transformed XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.example.com/type"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/type" elementFormDefault="unqualified" >

    <xs:element name="serviceResponse" type="MyServiceResponse"/>

    <xs:complexType name="MyServiceResponse">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="Body" type="Body" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Body">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="Car" type="Car" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Car">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="Brand" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="Color" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>    
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: The real XSD behind this issue is very complex and there are multiple. Although it would work it is quite tedious to create this kind of binding file for each of the XSDs. Do you know if there is a different solution to this? The core of the problem seems to be that the XmlStreamReader copies the `xlmns` namespace to the Body element, but not to Car. will add an example of what is in the XSR at the point of unmarshalling.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't seen any different solution to this.